# RewriteCond RewriteRule based on non-matching IP only before date

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am currently forwarding from RCUW.org (new upcoming website) to RiverCitiesUnitedWay.org (old website) for any visitors not matching internal staff - using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^(104.166.7.62|47.216.48.142|99.203.75.184|50.38.152.51)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rivercitiesunitedway.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I want to make it so that after the new year, the website goes live to the public (everyone). Basically so that it disregards the above IP address requirements after that date.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the fix.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^(104.166.7.62|47.216.48.142|99.203.75.184|50.38.152.51) [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20191231235959
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rivercitiesunitedway.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Although you stated in the question that RiverCitiesUnitedWay.org was the "old website"?

Answer (score 0):

> so that it disregards the above IP address requirements after that date

Presumably, you just don't want the redirect to the old website to occur at all? In which case, you can simply add an additional *condition* that references the `TIME_YEAR` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} =2019
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(104\.166\.7\.62|47\.216\.48\.142|99\.203\.75\.184|50\.38\.152\.51)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.old-website.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that, strictly speaking, you should be referencing the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable, not the `REMOTE_HOST` server variable. `REMOTE_HOST` may work OK on *your system* because your server is probably not configured to resolve remote IP addresses - this is not always the case.

Also, don't forget to escape the literal dots in the IP addresses. Otherwise the dot matches *any character* so could potentially match more users than anticipated.

Comment: Thank you Mr White for sharing your knowledge.